# Cant run R command from PHP. Paths issue?

Tags: php, linux, r

I am trying to run an R command from PHP using exec.  I know that it would make much more sense to use RServer, or a socket connection, but those options are currently not available to me.

The code looks like this:

```
$cmd = '/var/www/r.sh';
exec($cmd, $out, $return_var);
```

r.sh contains the following

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
cd /home/ubuntu
R CMD BATCH RFile.R
```

When I the command from the shell, it works absolutely fine.  When I run the command from PHP, I get the following error:

```
> test( read.csv("OutData.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,encoding="UTF-8"))
Error in library(randomForest) :
  there is no package called 'randomForest'
Calls: test -> library
Execution halted
```

My initial thought was that it might be permission related.  I have given www-data read an execute permission to everything to no avail.  I have also run the command from the shell as the www-data user and it works fine.  Its only when invoked from PHP that it fails.

So, I am now thinking that its a paths issue.  randomForest is an R library and is correctly installed on the box:

```
ubuntu@<removed>:/var/www$ sudo find / -name randomForest
/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/randomForest
/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/randomForest/R/randomForest
```

I can't find any shell environment variables which set up paths, so I don't understand why the command works from the shell, but not from PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: from within R, try `ss <- Sys.getenv(); ss[grep("^R_",names(ss))]`, or `ss[grep("^R_LIB",names(ss))]`

Comment: What should I be seeing here?  Looks like ss is populated with all the env data from the shell.  Unfortunately my experience with R is very very limited so I am not sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: `R_LIBS`, `R_LIBS_USER`.  (The "R Installation and Administration Manual", e.g. http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/doc/manuals/R-admin.html , is the reference for this stuff.)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  If you will put the above in an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant environment variables are `R_LIBS` and `R_LIBS_USER`; the [R Installation and Administration Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html) is the relevant reference.  If you want to see how these variables are set from within an R session, try

```
ss <- Sys.getenv()
ss[grep("^R_LIB",names(ss))]
```